# Fade in two divs together, but fade them out at different times

Tags: jquery, sequence, fadein, fadeout

I am using the following script which is a sequence of messages fading in and out in a "mytext" div.

I need the "toptext" div to fade in a message AT THE SAME TIME with "test 1" but then remain on screen and fade OUT with "test 2".

Sorry, I am a complete beginner, so struggling to figure it out! Any help, really appreciated!

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
  $(window).mousemove(function(){
    runIt();
  });
  runIt();      
})

function runIt() {
  var it = $('#myText');
  it.stop(true,true).clearQueue().fadeOut(1).animate({left:0},500).queue(function(){
    it.html('Start Again');
    it.dequeue();
  })
  it.fadeIn(500).animate({left:0},5000).fadeOut(1000).queue(function(){
    it.html('test 1');
    it.dequeue();
  })
  it.fadeIn(1000).animate({left:0},5000).fadeOut(1000).queue(function(){
    it.html('test 2');
    it.dequeue();
  })
  it.fadeIn(1000).animate({left:0},5000).fadeOut(1000).queue(function(){
    it.html('test 3');
    $(window).unbind('mousemove');
    it.dequeue();
  })
  it.fadeIn(1000);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="toptext"></div>
<div id="myText"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not wrap them both in a parent div. Fade the parent div in, then fade each of the child div's out.

Comment: THanks, Chris. How do I achieve that with the jquery script above? Sorry, I am a real beginner with javascript/jquery. I'm struggling to figure it out.